# Recursive Inverse FFT

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, fft, ifft

I have implemented two functions FFT and InverseFFT in recursive mode.

These are the functions:

```
def rfft(a):
    n = a.size
    if n == 1:
        return a
    i = 1j
    w_n = e ** (-2 * i * pi / float(n))
    w = 1
    a_0 = np.zeros(int(math.ceil(n / 2.0)), dtype=np.complex_)
    a_1 = np.zeros(n / 2, dtype=np.complex_)
    for index in range(0, n):
        if index % 2 == 0:
            a_0[index / 2] = a[index]
        else:
            a_1[index / 2] = a[index]
    y_0 = rfft(a_0)
    y_1 = rfft(a_1)
    y = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.complex_)
    for k in range(0, n / 2):
        y[k] = y_0[k] + w * y_1[k]
        y[k + n / 2] = y_0[k] - w * y_1[k]
        w = w * w_n
    return y

def rifft(y):
    n = y.size
    if n == 1:
        return y
    i = 1j
    w_n = e ** (2 * i * pi / float(n))
    w = 1
    y_0 = np.zeros(int(math.ceil(n / 2.0)), dtype=np.complex_)
    y_1 = np.zeros(n / 2, dtype=np.complex_)
    for index in range(0, n):
        if index % 2 == 0:
            y_0[index / 2] = y[index]
        else:
            y_1[index / 2] = y[index]
    a_0 = rifft(y_0)
    a_1 = rifft(y_1)
    a = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.complex_)
    for k in range(0, n / 2):
        a[k] = (a_0[k] + w * a_1[k]) / n
        a[k + n / 2] = (a_0[k] - w * a_1[k]) / n
        w = w * w_n
    return a
```

Based on the definition of IFFT, converting FFT function to IFFT function can be done by changing `2*i*pi` to `-2*i*pi` and dividing the result by `N`. The `rfft()` function works fine but the `rifft()` function, after these modifications, does not work.

I compare the output of my functions with `scipy.fftpack.fft` and `scipy.fftpack.ifft` functions.

I feed the following NumPy array:

```
a = np.array([1, 0, -1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

The following box shows the results of `rfft()` function and `scipy.fftpack.fft` function.

```
//rfft(a)
[ 3.00000000+0.j -1.12132034-1.12132034j 2.00000000+3.j 3.12132034-3.12132034j -3.00000000+0.j 3.12132034+3.12132034j 2.00000000-3.j -1.12132034+1.12132034j]
//scipy.fftpack.fft(a)
[ 3.00000000+0.j -1.12132034-1.12132034j 2.00000000+3.j 3.12132034-3.12132034j -3.00000000+0.j 3.12132034+3.12132034j 2.00000000-3.j -1.12132034+1.12132034j]
```

And this box shows the results of `rifft()` function and `scipy.fftpack.ifft` function.

```
//rifft(a)
[ 0.04687500+0.j -0.01752063+0.01752063j 0.03125000-0.046875j 0.04877063+0.04877063j -0.04687500+0.j 0.04877063-0.04877063j 0.03125000+0.046875j -0.01752063-0.01752063j]
//scipy.fftpack.ifft(a)
[ 0.37500000+0.j -0.14016504+0.14016504j 0.25000000-0.375j 0.39016504+0.39016504j -0.37500000+0.j 0.39016504-0.39016504j  0.25000000+0.375j -0.14016504-0.14016504j]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The division by the size `N` is a global scaling factor and should be performed on the result of the recursion rather than dividing at each stage of the recursion as you have done (by a decreasing factor as you go deeper in the recursion; overall scaling down the result too much). You could address this by removing the `/ n` factor in the final loop of your original implementation, which gets called by another function performing the scaling:

```
def unscaledrifft(y):
  ...
  for k in range(0, n / 2):
    a[k] = (a_0[k] + w * a_1[k])
    a[k + n / 2] = (a_0[k] - w * a_1[k])
    w = w * w_n
  return a

def rifft(y):
  return unscaledrifft(y)/y.size
```

Alternatively, since you are performing a radix-2 FFT, the global factor `N` would be a power of 2 such that `N=2**n`, where `n` is the number of steps in the recursion. You could thus divide by 2 at each stage of the recursion to achieve the same result:

```
def rifft(y):
  ...
  for k in range(0, n / 2):
    a[k] = (a_0[k] + w * a_1[k]) / 2
    a[k + n / 2] = (a_0[k] - w * a_1[k]) / 2
    w = w * w_n
  return a
```